# apache redirect with existing mod rewrite (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm changing domains for a wordpress site, and I would like any url for the old site to redirect to the new site, only rewriting the domain.

In other words:

- site.com should redirect to en.site.se
- site.com/page should redirect to en.site.se/page
- site.com/something/about/someone/and/so/on.jpg should redirect to en.site.se/something/about/someone/and/so/on.jpg

The current mod_rewrite looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I did try some new rewrite rules myself but i didn't manage to make things work correctly. I'm thinking to do something like replacing one occurrence of index.php with http://en.site.se

Here is some failed code:

```
#RewriteRule . http://en.site.se/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://en.site.se/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://en.site.se/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

change 302 to 301 once you get it working.